# Unity Admob Banner is not clickable

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, banner

I'm developing an Android game with Unity. I used [this](https://github.com/nabrozidhs/unity_admob_android) plugin for Admob. The Interstitial ad is clickable but when i click the banner nothing's happen. I tried [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/195169-Google-Admob-plugin-for-Unity-ad-is-not-clickable) but nothing's changed. Additionally, i tried add `com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity` Activity in manifest file and i got this error:

> Trying to merge incompatible
>   /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity]
>   element:

How can i solve this problem? Any suggestions will make me happy. Thanks.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!-- This file was automatically generated by the Google Play Games plugin for Unity
     Do not edit. -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.example.games.mainlibproj"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" /> 

    <application>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
                android:value="\ 123456789123" /> 
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
                android:value="\ 123456789123" /> 
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 
        <activity android:name="com.google.example.games.pluginsupport.SignInHelperActivity"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.example.games.pluginsupport.SelectOpponentsHelperActivity"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.example.games.pluginsupport.InvitationInboxHelperActivity"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>        

        <activity android:name ="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name ="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name ="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data  android:name ="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value ="true" />
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your minimum sdk version in unity. You have declared it 8 and in google play services by default min sdk is 9. Try changing your sdk to 9 in the unity and hope it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used another plugin and my both ads are clicable now.